# How can i change the color in the editor for the px and s values?

Tags: visual-studio-code

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ffBd2.png)

I can't find the name for the px and s (which are green) values so i can change them inside the `"editor.tokenColorCustomizations"`  in `settings.json` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 "editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "textMateRules": [
        {
          // "name": "CSS Class and Support - Class",
          "scope": [
            "keyword.other.unit.px.css",
            "keyword.other.unit.s.css",
          ],
          "settings": {
            "foreground": "#f00"
          }
       }
    ]
  }
```

Use the tool from the Command Palette:

`Developer: Inspect Editor Tokens and Scopes`

See [Scope Inspector](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/syntax-highlight-guide#scope-inspector).

[image: css scopes with the Scope Inspector]